# Why is my volume empty when binding it to a host folder?

Tags: android, docker, docker-compose

I was trying to setup a docker container to manage an Android SDK. I want other containers to be able to use the same SDK, for example my Jenkins container to build Android projects.

I found [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/thyrlian/android-sdk/) image which both installs an Android SDK and Gradle. Since I want to re-use the SDK and make it persistent, I created volume which is bound to a host folder. This is the `docker-compose.yml` file I use to start the container.

```
version: "2"

services:
  androidsdk:
    image: thyrlian/android-sdk:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: androidsdk
    volumes:
      - /srv/gradle:/opt/gradle
      - /srv/android-sdk:/opt/android-sdk
```

However, after starting the image with `docker-compose up`, the folders on my host and the matching folders in the container are empty.

If I start the container without the host volumes, the folders in the container are not empty and contain the SDK tools and Gradle.

I expected that the only difference would be, that the folders from the container are mirrored on my host and when removing the container I could still keep using the SDK from the host, if I link that folder to my other containers as well (e. g. Jenkins).

Why is the container "broken" with the host volumes and how can I get it to work the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

> I found this image which both installs an Android SDK and Gradle. Since I want to re-use the SDK and make it persistent, I created volume which is bound to a host folder. This is the docker-compose.yml file I use to start the container.

The SDK is already part of this image. It is persistent, as long as the image exists on the host.

By mounting a local volume into the container, you're actually removing the SDK.

Comment: Okay, that means the host folder has a higher "priority" and overwrites the container folder after it has been started? How can I change that? Do I have to start it without the host volume and then add this connection to the host folder later?

Comment: Limit the scope of the mount so that you're only targetting a directory that needs persisted. If the image provides the SDK, there's no point in using it with a local mount. What changes that you need to persist?

Comment: Wouldn't I have the same problem with any subfolder though? What I want is to be able to use the SDK, that this container sets up and updates, in other containers as well. And for that I would need the whole SDK, or I might run into problems if something is missing. That's why I wanted to mirror it on a host directory and then mount this directory (volume) as read-only from other containers. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: This image ALREADY contains the full SDK. Just re-use the image for other projects, you do not need to persist anything to disk.

Comment: It actually does not contain the *full* SDK. Just the manager to install parts of the SDK. Since Android is still actively developed, the SDK in this image will need to be updated every XX days, and thus it changes the container. How would I go about "re-using" this image? Sorry, I'm quite new to docker.

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose.yml` definition:

```
volumes:
      - /srv/android-sdk:/opt/android-sdk
```

I guess the `/srv/android-sdk` directory on your host machine is empty.  Thus you should first copy the pre-downloaded SDK to the host 'sdk' directory (as an initialization step, described in the [project's guide](https://github.com/thyrlian/AndroidSDK#getting-started)), then do `docker-compose up`.  In this way, the non-empty host 'sdk' directory will be mounted to container, and any update of SDK executed later inside the container will be persisted.

Please feel free to ask or create an issue ticket in the project repository.  Thanks.